# Why am I seeing a low F-statistic, but a very significant p-value in permanova?

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value, permutation-test, f-statistic, vegan

So I am having some numbers which I can't understand...basically I am performing a permanova test using the `adonis2` function, from the [vegan](https://github.com/vegandevs/vegan) package, and what I see is a very significant p-value with a very low f-statistic and I was wondering how this is possible.

This is what I have:

```
Permutation test for adonis under reduced model
Terms added sequentially (first to last)
Permutation: free
Number of permutations: 999

adonis2(formula = transposed_taxa ~ Treatment, data = adonis_meta, permutations = permuts, method = "bray", by = "terms")
          Df SumOfSqs      R2     F Pr(>F)
Treatment  1   0.3506 0.08074 1.581  0.002 **
Residual  18   3.9912 0.91926
Total     19   4.3418 1.00000
```

I also tried an online [F distribution calculator](https://www.statology.org/f-distribution-calculator/) and, if I did the computations correctly (i.e., filled the proper number of degrees of freedom), the calculator gives me a non-significant p-value for the f-statistic I get from the test. Also, I tried the other way around, i.e., I provided the p-value and I got a very high f-statistics. However, I may be completely wrong and/or this calculator does not work for permanova test.

What am I missing here?

EDIT:
this code provide the results i am seeing:

```
# load library
library("vegan")

# set seed
set.seed(131)

# build metadata
meta <- structure(list(treatment = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("treat", "ctrl"), class = "factor"), SampleID = c("smpl_001", 
"smpl_002", "smpl_003", "smpl_004", "smpl_005", "smpl_006", "smpl_007", "smpl_008", 
"smpl_009", "smpl_010", "smpl_011", "smpl_012", "smpl_013", "smpl_014", "smpl_015", 
"smpl_016", "smpl_017", "smpl_018", "smpl_019", "smpl_020")), row.names = c("smpl_001", 
"smpl_002", "smpl_003", "smpl_004", "smpl_005", "smpl_006", "smpl_007", "smpl_008", 
"smpl_009", "smpl_010", "smpl_011", "smpl_012", "smpl_013", "smpl_014", "smpl_015", 
"smpl_016", "smpl_017", "smpl_018", "smpl_019", "smpl_020"), class = "data.frame")

# build distance matrix with bray curtis metric
dist_mat <- structure(c(0.724637600797927, 0.810151211442847, 0.677040935047858, 
0.684990809226583, 0.773841077947218, 0.730965541771736, 0.721636429281786, 
0.670062302186762, 0.735219755374301, 0.726420817041101, 0.713890852756624, 
0.672481163496018, 0.770155244262034, 0.736284810905502, 0.725613337053673, 
0.729027437249588, 0.684174177335026, 0.731597842534973, 0.744984703810319, 
0.624016277905062, 0.716705596289758, 0.642368044368606, 0.660041089097984, 
0.683430554390529, 0.637694222022575, 0.696747540033531, 0.678073194220625, 
0.606862380345106, 0.57055508520052, 0.551073859282405, 0.685299854417393, 
0.576578503650073, 0.70888030875411, 0.753358012196228, 0.559701576529528, 
0.628139583570118, 0.616139151118536, 0.673897628859827, 0.688365913838432, 
0.600801291804287, 0.653870227670454, 0.713403074119784, 0.622562333387564, 
0.628100195801016, 0.638223638807926, 0.621583052281211, 0.639684018803079, 
0.658541917209453, 0.62143045183579, 0.711481887009044, 0.753101948589314, 
0.652118731984756, 0.669405500109936, 0.631233748354645, 0.681137745516244, 
0.75990843296923, 0.704545253550062, 0.733485020719486, 0.70159943122252, 
0.687665942056175, 0.71194111729798, 0.687556422198947, 0.672450715128387, 
0.729058498800823, 0.777450338280718, 0.724047236746885, 0.693695657946689, 
0.649024860632527, 0.743978052380142, 0.690306665100079, 0.66738824968164, 
0.666456720997265, 0.736939480231912, 0.701398808286334, 0.666061916019718, 
0.673314770321561, 0.678582532793769, 0.601722977395924, 0.694594001795866, 
0.666715778630456, 0.733905602972688, 0.708928297345911, 0.660957906863241, 
0.688380488856927, 0.66749857777161, 0.638562693219007, 0.709099622247953, 
0.661582073250648, 0.633361258020319, 0.64395516014329, 0.649660296892919, 
0.693266403675858, 0.619593981263679, 0.610426150945898, 0.680254103567928, 
0.704351725342505, 0.655961485324122, 0.682236566670637, 0.60440942570617, 
0.717559929520578, 0.678396363326736, 0.662793617648454, 0.657884773482801, 
0.611508752657517, 0.695249293387878, 0.641413832130993, 0.631289777942896, 
0.76873495257605, 0.7214801270069, 0.648605405437042, 0.638675714854417, 
0.690476980816459, 0.624196684143274, 0.716828273978603, 0.620623296876388, 
0.734305024372298, 0.696968360773382, 0.731531545670681, 0.590046390437714, 
0.656457660565246, 0.767672873743218, 0.662583670754548, 0.741384141808377, 
0.632153877463622, 0.686203048119573, 0.681849943901682, 0.679030715444911, 
0.695081943961127, 0.670973436524669, 0.655707226050489, 0.592390953713221, 
0.719296118412277, 0.681242617504174, 0.709011062976595, 0.67783231497305, 
0.628507609160785, 0.698992117288368, 0.692043273990139, 0.635338402719872, 
0.657103639492005, 0.716464174187625, 0.615559649585827, 0.695082938920572, 
0.667734702508218, 0.616496859490065, 0.642779258886188, 0.653646025092285, 
0.631693957514602, 0.611457903279869, 0.688517163734204, 0.737259708862597, 
0.603583398496329, 0.656242818753164, 0.597835522574495, 0.594058163092095, 
0.670135094778774, 0.621802926897363, 0.744151393706153, 0.723831207989047, 
0.563513462547226, 0.628881872570669, 0.62794706034554, 0.676684493053249, 
0.622600780389654, 0.698874934198522, 0.7223868940598, 0.552933805235236, 
0.664090363014779, 0.611138112893922, 0.596969123444625, 0.73702614785897, 
0.66350703692813, 0.648073310354135, 0.611886898022537, 0.698582583703285, 
0.683497738003825, 0.753238008973899, 0.637095874502176, 0.625844086528647, 
0.629241237689765, 0.732814733043977, 0.641962575290711, 0.769763636147583, 
0.711868946785738, 0.701186509994886, 0.689603853801978, 0.766601551308245, 
0.634042239970803, 0.624152094184768, 0.701782607184278), maxdist = 1, Size = 20L, Labels = c("smpl_001", 
"smpl_002", "smpl_003", "smpl_004", "smpl_005", "smpl_006", "smpl_007", "smpl_008", 
"smpl_009", "smpl_010", "smpl_011", "smpl_012", "smpl_013", "smpl_014", "smpl_015", 
"smpl_016", "smpl_017", "smpl_018", "smpl_019", "smpl_020"), Diag = FALSE, Upper = FALSE, method = "bray", class = "dist")

# run test
print(adonis2(dist_mat~treatment, data=meta, permutations=999, by="terms"))
```

Comment: You apparently have quite a small dataset. Can you edit your post to include the data (by pasting in the output of `dput(adonis_meta)`) and the code you ran?

Comment: the dataset comprises 20 samples (10 for each treatment) and ~4.5k taxa since these are ecology data. so, yes it may be possible that the number of samples is small but i have no idea how big the average dataset looks like. and i am afraid i won't be able to upload the dataset.

Comment: you could post the dissimilarity matrix which should (i think?) be sufficient for this test.

Comment: @GeorgeSavva, yep, indeed it is. i did it, thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a reason why the tests are based on permutation instead of nominal values of *F*-statistic. The reason is that nominal values of *F*-statistic are not correct in this setting, but we must find the empirical distribution under null model from permutations.

You can have a look at the permutation distribution of *F* using function `permustats` to extract permutation values (randomized values) and `densityplot` and other support functions to display those values, or `densityplot(permustats(<yourmodel>))`.

Comment: ok, so the F statistics that i see in the result is this pseudo-F that is used to compute the p value using the formula mentioned in the wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutational_analysis_of_variance). so, the pvalue is giving me the likelihood of observing a F statistic that is bigger (more extreme) than the one `adonis2` is returning? what does this tells me about the data, though?

Comment: The interpretation is the same as with normal _F_-values in frequentist testing and it tells you the same thing about data as usual frequentist _P_-values: probability of your data given Null model.

Comment: alright, thank you!